# Adding doubleclick action through plugin.xml in ProblemsView

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In the problems view, an editor will be opened when I double click the marker. My requirement is that the marker should not open the editor. Without extending the problems view, I should be able to do override double click functionality and I shouldn't create one more view.

Is this possible? If it is please let me know how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for changing the double click / open action in the problems view (`org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.ProblemsView`)